# Add filestream to an existing table column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following table column:

```
[Content] [varbinary](max) NULL
```

And I want to make it a filestream column so I tried:

```
alter table dbo.Files
  alter column Content add filestream
```

But I get the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'filestream'.
```

I also tried

```
alter table dbo.Files
  alter column Content varbinary(max) filestream not null
```

But I got the error:

```
Cannot alter column 'Content' in table 'Files' to add or remove the FILESTREAM column attribute.
```

How can I add filestream to an existing column?

Comment: I have suspicion you may have to create another column "alter table dbo.Files
  add Content_new varbinary(max) filestream not null" then copy what you have in the original column over.

Answer (score 10):

you'll need to do the following (sourced from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e4ae96e8-fe79-4235-a89b-018e3db26541/how-to-add-filestream-attribute-to-an-existing-column?forum=transactsql)):

```
/* rename the varbinary(max) column
eg. FileData to xxFileData */
sp_RENAME '<TableName>.<ColumnName>', 'xx<ColumnName>' , 'COLUMN'
GO

/* create a new varbinary(max) FILESTREAM column */
ALTER TABLE <TableName>
ADD <ColumnName> varbinary(max) FILESTREAM NULL
GO

/* move the contents of varbinary(max) column to varbinary(max) FILESTREAM column */
UPDATE <TableName>
SET <ColumnName> = xx<ColumnName>
GO

/* drop the xx<ColumnName> column */
ALTER TABLE <TableName>
DROP COLUMN xx<ColumnName>
GO
```

Comment: If you encounter an error message "A table that has FILESTREAM columns must have a nonnull unique column with the ROWGUIDCOL property." you can add this property to a column with the following T-SQL statement: `ALTER TABLE <TableName> ALTER COLUMN <IdColumnName> ADD ROWGUIDCOL`. Note that the column <IdColumnName> must be of type uniqueidentifier.